# How should I go about making a long cable for receiving UHF radio signals?

Tags: antenna, cables

I want to connect antenna(s) to radio receiving equipment. The antenna(s) are PL-259 and the receiving equipment is SMA.

I have only found at best a 20 foot PL-259 to SMA cable, so it seems I have to string multiple cables together, but I am concerned about setting up reflections or changing impedance or whatever or doing something that will degrade my signal.

Should I just get 50 foot lengths of PL-259 to PL-259 and string them together to length, then get PL-259 to SMA jumper cable and put it on the end as the final step? If I do this, I will have some random length of cable that will not be matched to the frequency, or does that not matter?

I see I can also get 50 foot lengths of unterminated cable, so I suppose I could start soldering cables together and terminating them myself. Is there any benefit to spending a lot of time doing this?

Comment: How critical is the signal?  How long are the cables? Do you need to do this once, or will you be doing several installations?

Comment: UHF: are we talking 301 MHz or 2.99GHz

Comment: Is this an X-Y problem, where the cable length issue could be resolved by placing the receiver within 50ft of the antenna, and some other medium used for the rest of the distance?

Comment: @TylerDurden:  I notice o´you almost never accept answers.  Do none of them solve your problems?

Comment: @JRE I notice that did not upvote my question. So, you thought my question was good enough that you would spend 15 minutes writing an answer to it, but no so good enough it was worth upvoting?

Comment: I'm not concerned about my answer.  It is just that you have asked so many questions and have accepted so few.  I just wondered if you never got the answers you needed.

Comment: @JRE If I haven't accepted an answer, it's either because the "answer" did not solve or explain a solution or was not definitive, or because my question got zero votes. My feeling about it, is that if my question is worthless, then so are their answers. In cases where I consider an answer helpful but not definitive, then I will upvote the answer but not accept it.

Comment: @TylerDurden I'm an admin. Your voting choices are very largely yours to make.  General protocol is to accept the best answer provided by people who spent the effort on it. It's true that in some cases no definitive answers may be given, but if this is found to be the case more often than not it's possible (but not certain) that a different approach to question asking may be profitable.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need several cables of at least 100 feet.

I'd buy a roll of good cable (low loss RG58, or something specified for your frequency range) some PL-259 connectors, and some SMA connectors.  Buy good connectors with the appropriate crimping tools.

Follow the contruction procedures for the connectors religiously.  Do it right and your connectors will have next to no influence on your signal.  Do it wrong, and you could lose nearly all your signal in the connector.

Use PL-259 only at the antenna end (and only because your antennas already have the SO-239 on them.)  PL-259 and SO-239 are not well specified at the frequencies commonly called "UHF" today.  [Back in 1930 (when PL-259 was designed,)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UHF_connector) UHF was up to 100MHz.  Today, UHF goes up to GHz range.

Try not to chain multiple cables together.  Each joint has a bit of mismatch and loss.  Not much with good connectors, but it does add up.

Make each cable to the correct length so you only have two connectors to deal with.

[SMA is rated to at least 12GHz,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA_connector) so you should be fine using the SMA connector.

---

There's lower loss cable than RG-58, but you have to have matching connectors for the cable type.  RG-58 ought to be good to over 2GHz, and connectors and tools should be common and (relatively) inexpensive.

---

Keep in mind that an antenna with a long cable installed on a house or other building is a first class lightning rod.  You'll need to take care of proper grounding of the antenna(s) and cables.

Answer (score 0):

Typically they make the stuff in 1000' or 500m lengths. if you can find a cable maker they should be able to do you a long enough cable.